# Объединение 2 баз данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 2 базы данных MySQL на разных серверах (А и B), в каждой 60+ таблиц, в которых от 100 до 1 мил. записей. Есть задача сделать скрипт для сбора всех данных в третью базу X на отдельном сервере.

Сейчас запрос выглядит так:

```
$max_id = $mysqliX->query("SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); //id - Primary key и автоинкрементное
$table_max_id = $max_id->fetch_row(); // получаем $table_max_id[0]  

$new_entries = $mysqliA->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > $table_max_id[0]");  //выбираем все новые значения
```

Ну а дальше циклом `while` записываю всё в базу X.
То же самое проделываю и для второй базы. 
В результате всё происходит очень долго.

Даже скрипт подсчета новых записей, который вместо `SELECT *` и вставки использует просто `SELECT count(*)` работает 3-4 минуты.

Подскажите, как можно ускориться? 
Можно ли в один запрос поместить селект из разных баз? И поможет ли это?
Prepared `INSERT` сильно ускорит процесс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставку можно ускорить.

**Вариант 1**. Делать вставку не по одной записи, а группами например по 1000 записей, запросы будут иметь вид

```
INSERT INTO your_table (col1, col2, col3, ...)
VALUES
(value11, value12, value13, ...),
(value21, value22, value23, ...),
...
(valueN1, valueN2, valueN3, ...)
```

**Вариант 2**. Грузить данные с помощью [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Вариант 1 уже использую (вставляю по 100 записей). По поводу селектов и вставки через файл - селект не будет работать дольше, учитывая, что придётся записывать сначала в файл, а потом ещё и читать оттуда?

Comment: На мой взгляд вариант `INSERT INTO db2.your_table (...) SELECT ... FROM db1.your_table ...` очень хорош, но если базы на разных серверах, то вряд ли так получится. `LOAD DATA INFILE` работает раз в 20 быстрее, чем INSERT. Подробнее: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-speed.html

Comment: Попробовал на табличке с 450 000 строк. SELECT/INSERT занимает около 100 секунд, LOAD DATA INFILE примерно 15 секунд.